# (AutoMapper) How to map an object which has a list of different objects?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, automapper

I have a LearningElement:

```
public class LearningElement
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

And some kinds of learning elements:

```
public class Course : LearningElement
{
  public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class Question: LearningElement
{
  public string Statement { get; set; }
}
```

Now I have a formation that can have many learning elements:

```
public class Formation 
{
  public ICollection<LearningElement> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

And finally my view models:

```
public class LearningElementModel
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class CourseModel : LearningElementModel
{
  public string Content { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionModel: LearningElementModel
{
  public string Statement { get; set; }
}

public class FormationModel
{
  public ICollection<LearningElementModel> Elements { get; set; }
}
```

So I do create maps:

```
AutoMapper.CreateMap<LearningElement, LearningElementModel>().ReverseMap();
AutoMapper.CreateMap<Course, CourseModel>().ReverseMap();
AutoMapper.CreateMap<Question, QuestionModel>().ReverseMap();
AutoMapper.CreateMap<Formation, FormationModel>().ReverseMap();
```

Now, suppose I have this view model

```
var formationModel = new FormationModel();
formationModel.Elements.Add(new CourseModel());
formationModel.Elements.Add(new QuestionModel());
```

And I do the mapping to a Formation object:

```
var formation = new Formation();
Automapper.Mapper.Map(formationModel, formation);
```

The problem is that formation has a list with learning elements, and not a list with a Question element and a Course element.

AutoMapper ignores that the elements in `formationModel.Elements` are not exactly a `LearningElementModel`, but a `QuestionModel` and `CourseModel`.

How can I correct this mapping?

Comment: I just wondering so I asked.Lets say u fill formationModel  with the CourseModel and QuestionModel and its values.How u planing to read those model values.As FormationModel only has LearningElementModel which is only contain Id fieald

Comment: With a JsonConverter where I can get a TypeName property and creates the good object!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use Include function from AutoMapper

```
AutoMapper.CreateMap<LearningElementModel, LearningElement>()
    .Include<CourseModel, Course>()
    .Include<MultipleChoiceQuestionModel, MultipleChoiceQuestion>();
```